# Laravel reset forgotten password

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, reset-password

I have never done this before. Now I want to create a way for user to reset their forgotten password. I know I could have run `php artisan make:auth` but the thing is, I don't use the methods that laravel gives. I have many things different and I don't even use AuthController. Now I know I can probably make `resetpassword` table and put my tokens in there, but the problem is, these tokens I put in there won't get removed if the user does not use the token. So it feels like a lot of security issues to care about. I'm looking for easier solutions or things that I do not know.

Comment: What security issues are you worried about?

Comment: When someone request for reset password then generate a token and save into database and also set the reset password token expire time. If someone again request then override previous one. And on every successfully reset password(for a user) check invalid or expire token(for all users) and simple remove that or set-up a cron job for this.

Comment: @AliN11 if the token remains in database, someone might find the token. it allows to change password with no barriers

Comment: @Nikonah: The token which sent to the user email, is different from the token which stored in database. The token in database is hashed. So nobody can't detect and match tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry. First I have to say that Laravel has more than 400 contributors [in GitHub](https://github.com/laravel/laravel). The issue that you mentioned is an ordinary one.

When you send a reset password link to a user, a token is generated. This token will be send to the user email address and hashed token will be stored in `password_resets` table.

The sent reset password link looks like this:

```
http://www.example.com/password/reset/362f8adcf97f022cbf1a6347cee191d95f02b454aeee53a85e592b0b6fb1a4cb
```

And this is what stored in database:

```
+------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
|      email       |                             token                             |     created_at      |
+------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
| mail@example.com | $2y$10$O16XcqD6oknXBskCml9K7eCvO7.Te112YLE.XNulvT.K3XjUymBkm  | 2018-05-26 18:18:04 |
+------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
```